# «Это не то, что раньше...» Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Это не то, что раньше...**
Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потребность в запятой зависит от продолжения фразы - образуют ли слова "не то что раньше" цельное сочетание или они оказываются на стыке сложноподчинённого предложения:

> Это **не то что раньше**, а недопустимо рано.
>
> Это **не то, что раньше** было.

(ср. Тогда не то, что ныне, При государыне служил Екатерине. /Грибоедов/)

Comment: Это не то что раньше – вкрутил лампочку, и все....Вот так!

Comment: Почти как у Грибоедова :)

Comment: У Розенталя пример без запятой: "Сейчас здесь не то что раньше, всё стало интереснее".(?!) Я этого примера не понимаю. Нет ли тут ошибки. У него же : "Ср. при другом характере сочетания: Вы говорите не то, что думаете."  По-моему, оба примера отностятся к "другому характеру сочетания"

Comment: Вот тут понятно: "И не то что трое суток, и десятеро суток подождете! (Л. Толстой);".   По-моему, "не то что Х" говорит, что Х неверно, или неточно, или недостаточно. По-моему, "не то что раньше" говорит, что слово *раньше* неточно отражает ситуацию. А "сейчас не то, что раньше" говорит, что то сейчас здесь не так, как раньше. Тут запятая нужна!

Comment: Примеры в ответе неудачные,  не раскрывают тему. В частности противопоставление встречается редко, пример нетипичный,  к данной теме относится косвенно, а других примеров (парных вариантов с фразеологическим сочетанием) нет. И теоретически только два варианта указаны, а их не два, а больше.  Так что не так просто решить эту задачу, нужен индивидуальный подход  и грамматический анализ в каждом случае.

Comment: @flossyU Судя по завершающему восклицанию, простое вкручивание лампочки относится к _новому_ положению дел, которое оценивается положительно, и эта радость выражается _цельным_ сочетанием, мало отличающимся от "это вам не фунт изюму" (запятая **не** нужна).

Comment: @flossyU  В Нацкорпусе есть выражение  "и всё тут". В БОЛЬШИНСТВЕ случаев оно  обособляется, причем и запятой, и тире. Обособление связано с наличием паузы. Выражения похожи, пауза тоже есть, поэтому запятую надо ставить. http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E8+%E2%F1%B8+%F2%F3%F2

Answer (score 4):

**Разные есть грамматические конструкции**: с фразеологическим оборотом ***не то что раньше*** (= не как раньше) и без него.

1) Простое предложение: Теперь **не то что раньше**. (Теперь не как раньше.)

2) СПП: Время теперь **не то, что раньше**. (Теперь не так, как раньше.)

3) Обособленный оборот: Теперь по-другому, **не то что раньше** (не как раньше).

Примеры:

**1)** Сейчас, знаете, дети какие растут сообразительные! **Не то что раньше.** Акселерация! [Ирина Пивоварова.  (1986)]

**2)** Конечно, сейчас время **не то, что** (было) раньше. [Галина Щербакова.  «Новый Мир», 2002]

Это **теперь не то, что раньше**, это же надо понимать, у любого встречного-поперечного закурить не возьмешь. [Л. Н. Разумовская. (1990-1999)]

У меня уже зрение **не то, что раньше**. [Валентин Постников. Карандаш и Самоделкин на Северном полюсе (1996)]

**3)** Теперь начнется совсем другая, новая жизнь, **не то что раньше**. [Ольга Шевченко. , 2002]

Сейчас искусство сильное, **не то что раньше**... [Галина Щербакова.  (2002)]

Поэтому я и не думала торопиться (**не то что раньше**). [Людмила Синицына. 1999.04.15]

В кабинках зашуршала настоящая туалетная бумага ― **не то что раньше**. [Виктор Пелевин. Девятый сон Веры Павловны (1991)]

Comment: Это преамбула, а вердикт какой?

Comment: Фраза: Это не то что раньше – вкрутил лампочку, и все....Вот так! –

Comment: склоняюсь поставить запятую, но второй корректор со мной не согласен...

Comment: Вердикт? Розенталь, наше всё, учит нас тому, что устойчивые обороты приравниваются по значению к одному слову и выполняют различные грамматические функции, которые надо определить.  В то же время  оборот может потерять фразеологическую цельность, и тогда он распадается на исходные составляющие со своими собственными функциями, которые тоже требуют определения. Поэтому не ищите У Розенталя ответа на каждое предложение (он дает общие указания), проводите анализ самостоятельно.

Comment: Это не то что раньше – вкрутил лампочку, и все...  Здесь явная пауза, обозначенная тире. О грамматике: это БСП,  вторая часть распространяет и проясняет первую, но запятой здесь недостаточно, для запятой нужны дополнительные структурные элементы, проясняющие отношения (наречия. местоимения и т.д.).

Comment: В первой части: ЭТО - подлежащее, оборот в роли сказуемого.

Comment: Jasmin, a Вы не находите, что есть пауза  после ТО: "Это не то [пауза], что раньше", а посему требуется запятая?

Comment: Долго я читала оба варианта и вот что думаю.  Надо сравнить: это не кАк раньше - это не тО что раньше.  Скорее всего, ударение падает на КАК и на ТО, а на "раньше" не падает вообще, и тогда паузы и запятой нет.

Answer (score 3):

[**Из Розенталя:**](http://www.rosental-book.ru/punct_xxix.html)

> § 114. Цельные по смыслу выражения:
>
> <...>
>
> 2. **Запятая не ставится внутри сочетаний *не то что, не то чтобы, не так чтобы, не иначе как,*** например: <...> *Сейчас здесь **не то что
>      раньше**, всё стало интереснее.*